# Bluetooth receiver (H-163) makes noise

Tags: bluetooth

I just bought a Bluetooth receiver and whenever I connect it to the radio it started to make some weird noises like *beep* constantly. I then decided to take a look to this problem on the internet and the solution that I found was to connect it to a 6V supply(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JupcaTRKYk), but if I connect it to 6V it randomly turns off, which didn't happen on the normal connector (5V). What can I do to solve it? I'm new in electronics so maybe you can give me a hand on this.
Here is a diagram of the Bluetooth receiver and some specifications:
[image]
And my power supply is a modified cellphone charger which I change the Zener diode for a 6.2V one:
**input**:100-240Vac; 50/60Hz; 0.35A
|||**output**: 6.2V---2A

Comment: Agustin, it is difficult to answer your question, because you didn't tell us what is your BT receiver. That's because probably this problem only shows up in some kind of device. By the way, in electronics, we don't say "6V current": Volts are a measure of electric potential, not current. You didn't said where you found this solution to connect the module to 6V, but, the better option would be to follow the instructions of the maker of the device: which are the specs of the device? 5V or 6V? It would help if you add a schematic showing how you connected it, and which power source you are using.

Comment: Questions on the usage of products are generally off topic.  Your modification of a phone charger sounds quite suspect, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is power supply noise that is causing the buzz sound to come.
This happened to one of my tutors and it used the power supply isolation to remove the noise using any 5V to 5V isolation circuit.

You can also buy a new good power supply from some reputed company, 6V is not needed at all. 5V will work fine.

Comment: Answers on this site must stand on their own, they may not rely on external links for the key technical content.  That's true for all links, but doubly so for video links, as video is a horribly inefficient way to present technical information.  It would strongly appear that the question itself does not belong on this site.